# C++ reading txt files into a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, oop

I am creating a battleship game using c++, we have to load text files which contain the user's guesses & another file which contains the boat locations. I am approaching this by loading the data from the files into a 2D array. The goal is to be able to compare the two 2D arrays in order to determine if the user has won the game. I am struggling with loading the data into the array. This is my code for inputting the Users guess file.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "openconfigfile.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void openconfigfile()
{
    int row = 12;

    //Open the file in the location specified by user  
    ifstream file("C: Project Files\\Proj01_files\\in1.txt");

    //Check that the file was opened & loaded into array 
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "User input file has been loaded." << endl;
        string inputarray[12][2];

        while (file.good()) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 2; col++) {
                file >> inputarray[12][2];
            }
            row++;
        }

    }
    else cout << "Unable to open user input file.Please check your file path is correct.";
    file.close();

}
```

I know there is something wrong with the while loop since every time I run the project it tells me that my project file has stopped working. I am not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a few steps back, go back [to some good beginners books](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) and start reading about arrays again.

Comment: file >> inputarray[12][2];

What is this line doing????

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is the variable row doing?

```
 int row = 12;
```

Why is it initialized to 12?

Making assumptions on your code, it should be

```
int row = 0;
```

In the while loop, you can change the condition to eof

```
while (file.good())
```

This should be

```
while (!file.eof())
```

You are using the for loop but feeding the data in the same index of the array because of this LOC

```
file >> inputarray[12][2];
```

Again making assumptions on your code,

```
file >> inputarray[row][col];
```

This makes your function as following.

```
int row = 0;

//Open the file in the location specified by user  
ifstream file("C: Project Files\\Proj01_files\\in1.txt");

//Check that the file was opened & loaded into array 
if (file.is_open())
{
    cout << "User input file has been loaded." << endl;
    string inputarray[12][2];

    while (!file.eof()) {//EOF is end of file, if the file end hasn't reached, keep looping
        for (int col = 0; col < 2; col++) {
            file >> inputarray[row][col];
        }
        row++;
    }

}
else cout << "Unable to open user input file.Please check your file path is correct.";
file.close();
```

As the comment of @Someprogrammerdude states, you should really go back a few steps and learn more about arrays.

But still it's a great try to learn programming and filing. Hope i helped!

Comment: Please note that if the row exceeds 12, it would give an exception because your 2D array is basically a 12 by 2 array. So you can add an addition check in your while loop

'while(!file.eof()&&row<12)'

If you expect your file to contain more than 12 rows.